# Getting an uxepected token error using reactjs and nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

When creating a simple button that counts the clicks i get the unexpected token error on the button tag for (what i can tell) no reason

```
import React from 'react';

/**
 * A counter button: tap the button to increase the count.
 */
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => {this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });}}>
        Count: {this.state.count}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
export default Counter;
```

Comment: Your code runs fine on my system. Can you post the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Unexpected token (16:6) on the first "<" in <button

Comment: @LuiGiovanni Are you transpiling?

Comment: No, im compiling

Comment: you need to transpile your React code written in ES6 to ES5 using a ES6 to ES5 transpiler like babel, so that the browser can understand the JS code.

Comment: Oh im sorry, i am using Babel and webpack, forgive me for my mistake

Comment: Can you post your webpack config please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing presets in webpack.config.js.
Try this

```
module : {
        rules:[
            { 
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use : {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ['env','react']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
}
```